# angular-moment not available in karma mocha tests - requirejs?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, mocha.js, karma-runner, angular-moment

I'm trying to use angular-moment in a coffeescript AngularJS app that I'm building with gulp.  It's working fine in the app, no problems there, but when I try to run my karma + mocha test suite it fails, with this:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularMoment due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angularMoment' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I have angular-moment loaded as a dependency in my app, obviously:

```
angular.module("prometheus", [
  'ui.router'
  'ngAnimate'
  'angularMoment'
])
```

and I'm loading it in the script tags

```
script(src='vendors/moment/moment.js')
script(src='vendors/angular-moment/angular-moment.js')
```

Which is all I needed to use it in my app - as noted, it works fine there, but when I run my formerly-working karma/mocha tests, *boom*.

I've tried adding it to my karma.conf.coffee *(leaving out a lot of detail)*:

```
module.exports = (config) ->
  config.set
    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js'
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
      'bower_components/angular-ui-router/**/*.js'
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js'
      'bower_components/underscore/underscore.js'
      'bower_components/moment/moment.js'
      'bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js'
      ### Lots more left out
    ]
```

Which fails by printing out angular-moment.js and:

```
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
at /Users/stephancom/.../node_modules/requirejs/require.js:141
```

I've also tried adding various things to my test-main.coffee inspired by [this angular-moment issue](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/issues/36) also to no avail.

Ah yes, in case it matters, I'm loading angular-moment through bower, but I've also tried it via npm, and I'm using this version:

```
"angular-moment": "~0.10.1"
```

Am I missing something obvious, or does moment and/or angular-moment not like requirejs or ????  I'm fairly new to Angular and I've been struggling with this one for a day or two.